# How do I access object keys that show as undefined with direct reference to them but appear correctly when console logging?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am doing an HTTPS request function and getting back an auth code I want to use.

I put the returned data from the request into a variable and when I console log the variable like so:

```
console.log(authResponse);
```

It produces:

```
{"auth_token":"gergerqv4rg","email":"newemail@email.com","first_name":"Guy","last_name":"Simpson"}
```

When I take that same variable and reference auth_token like so:

```
console.log(authResponse.auth_token);
```

Then it returns undefined. Going the same for email or the other keys produces the same result.

When I try something like:

```
    Object.keys(authResponse)
```

It produces:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40, ... 154
```

Stopping at 154...

Trying to reference whatever that is produces random integers....

authResponse[0] = 123

authResponse[1] = 34

authResponse[2] = 97

authResponse[3] = 117

How do I reference my authResponse object's auth_token value?

Comment: Sounds to me that the response is not an object. Have you tried to parse it before inspecting properties? `JSON.parse(authResponse)`

Comment: I'll try that thanks for the idea, as far as I know anything in brackets with key value pairs is an object.

Comment: You are correct about the syntax format, but console.log could make you think you've got an object if the string is in the proper format. It's a combination of understanding the browser's console logging feature and simple debugging in the browser window on the client side.

Comment: That did the trick now I can reference it thanks so much for the replies friends!

Comment: Awesome! I made my comments an answer. If you could mark the post as the answer, I would appreciate it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` can make you think you've got an `Object` if the string is in the proper format. Be sure you are looking at an object, not a string.

When you determine the value is a `String`, parse the data into an object and you should be able to get the properties and values from it.

```
var authResponseObj = JSON.parse(authResponse);
console.log(authResponseObj.auth_token);
```